# How do you add a custom field to a menu link in Drupal 7?

Tags: routes, media

I am currently using the menu module (Drupal 7 Core) to manage my menus. A menu link consists on only a title and a description. **I would like to add an image field as well as another text field**. I have considered using taxonomy rather than menu links, but I still want the capability to add a basic page to a menu.

I have looked into a module called Menu Attributes http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes, but it doesn't add an image field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Menu icons](http://www.drupal.org/project/menu_icons) should do what you're after.

> This module allows you to upload an image in the menu-item's configuration form.
>
> After uploading the image, the icon data will be added to the menu link's
> options array.

Comment: My Android has FUBARed the formatting of this answer.  If someone could fix it I'd be grateful =)

Comment: This will do! Although, I would have liked to customize the min/max dimensions, but I does allow me to use an image style which is just fine. Bonus points for a module that will allow me to add more fields to a menu item (such as a field collection or text area)

Comment: @tytho Nothing at the moment but it looks like [menu links will be entities in Drupal 8](http://drupal.org/node/916388) so you'll be able to attach fields to them at some point in 2013 ;)